# Return nested object stored on rails json field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a json field

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
```

I have a json field with a field reference to another object,

```
my_json {
  id: 123 # reference to another object
}
```

I now want to write a query that will return the nested object.

Comment: This has that unessicary JSON anti-pattern stench all over it. If your data has relations to other entities then don't shove it in a JSON column.

Comment: If you actually really had to work with this you would have to write an insane join with something like `SELECT other_table.json_column JOIN other_table ON other_table.json_column->'id' = my_models.my_json->'id'` and you're forgoing the use of effective indexes, assocations and foreign keys for referential integrity. Don't do it. This is extremely simplefied - it will actually vary across RDBMS:es and if you have stacked levels of monstrosity like trying to get objects out of an array the queries get insane.